# Cannot connect open First Form from Second

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I cannot open my First Form from Second ,also i cannot pass variables between forms...I can open first form and then from there i can open second form but not vice versa.I got a lot of nonsense errors for example "StreamWriter is not declared" but that worked before i tried to connect Second and First form.

I tried something in linker options(tbh i'm not very familiar with that),i tried to pass values with globals variables but that also didn't work.

```
//Part of include code
#pragma once
#include "Form1.h"
//When i tried to open form1
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
Form1^ f1 = gcnew Form1();
 f1->Show();
}
```

I expect to open form1 from form2,and pass variables between them.

Comment: If this is the code in Form2.h then you almost certainly created a circular dependency between the .h files.  Since Form1.h has an #include "Form2.h".  Such are the hazards of C++, it uses a single-pass compilation model.  You have to do the normal C++ song and dance and move that code to Form2.cpp.   Which can #include both.  Otherwise one of the standard reasons why everybody recommends you don't write Winforms code in C++/CLI.  And worth noting that it is almost always wrong to have a second window re-create the first window again.

Comment: I just read about " circular dependency "  and I think you are right that's case.I don't have knowledge about that(They don't teach us about that in high school),i will study that i try to fix my problem.Thank you.

Comment: Talk to your teacher, you shouldn't be doing this.  Or don't and make all the mistakes you need to make to become a good programmer, quite okay with me.